# how to host a website in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am planning to host my html/css/js website in GCP. What services should I use and what is the monthly cost per 100 visitors/users?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Cloud Storage for it if you have static website. [This](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) tutorial explains how to configure a Cloud Storage bucket to host a static website for a domain you own. Please try to go through it to get more information about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

There are several option at Google cloud Platform for hosting basic static websites to Large Dynamic one. Below are some Products you can use:-

---

**1. Compute Engine:**- It is the best option if you are planning to expand and using other technology as well. If comfortable with basic linux commands, you can run your own server instance or can use cloud control panels. I recommend you to use Runcloud/Serverpilot Cloud panel which provides UI for managing multiple websites. You can manage websites having PHP to in these servers. You can have many tutorials available online for these.

---

**2. App Engine:-** It is affordable solution which works not only works static but for PHP,Python based websites too. These are managed by Google Cloud. So, it is also a good option.

---

**3. Storage Bucket:-** If You always wanna stick with only these technology js/html and css. It is also a good option.

---

I hope I was able to answer your query in a detailed manner. Consider upvoting if i helped!!